# what are the difference between initialize() and __init__() methods in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I recently saw usage of `initialize()` method along with  `__init__()` over [here](https://github.com/taesungp/contrastive-unpaired-translation/blob/master/options/base_options.py#L23) but, unable to get my head around the difference between both. At a first glance, it seems both are doing the same job (of initializing a class) but, wondering is there any difference in their execution?

Comment: `initialize()` is just a name of a function, it could have been called `some_function()` and still have the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

`__init__` is a python object method that has a special functionality that can't be replaced without the `__init__` function.

These are called `magic` or `dunder` methods but not all dunder methods are necessarily `magic`.

The magic functions are for the customization of the lifespan of the objects that are created from the type that they've been implemented.

`__init__` runs *right* after the object is created. `initialize` in your example however is just a method of the object.

There are numerous features coming from numerous amount of magic methods that are listed in the datamodel part of the documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names